# jquery theme builder question

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How do I initialize a button as an icon using the JQuery themeroller? I dont want text next to an icon, I just want an icon, and I want to switch between two icons when clicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do it this way:

```
<button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-carat-1-n"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-n"></span></button>
```

However, I haven't tested it-- this is directly from the ThemeRoller page. Just change the ID of the button and add your event to it. Also, make sure you change the ui-icon-carat-1-n class of the span to change the icon.